# Linux file access via jenkins Permission Denied

Tags: linux, excel, selenium, jenkins

I am running selenium test via jenkins. All packages are uploaded to linux server. In my test there is need of reading and writing to excel.

Every time when I upload new xls file, I have to run following command :

**chmod 777 path/test.xls**

If I replace new excel on linux and run build via jenkins without run above command, Jenkins says permission denied.

Is there any command which set permanent permission to access file from linux?

Answer (score 1):

you can change the permission for directory as recursive using the `-R` option, so when the file is placed in the folder it will have the same permission as the directory.

try this :

```
chmod -R 777 path/
```

Note:
This will change all the files and subfolders in the directory to 777